# Нечестная проверка на внимательность в очереди

Tags: обсуждение

[Нечестная проверка на внимательность в очереди.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158365/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-html-css) Считаю, что этот вопрос следует закрыть т.к. он содержит код скриншотом, а это не по правилам .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, код картинкой - так себе. Впрочем, первая картинка служит ещё и скриншотом результата, а не только кода. Тем не менее, сам по себе вопрос хороший и полезный, так что его надо не закрывать, а отредактировать.

Что касается очередей проверки, то давно известно, что они автоматические, из-за чего в них иногда оказывается что-то подозрительное. Редкие ошибки на таких проверках ни к чему плохому не приводят.